# Jenkins aws elastic deployment plugin just create a new ec2 on each update

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, jenkins, elastic-beanstalk

Here is something strange happening when I tries to deploy from Jenkins to Elastic Beanstalk , you can check my previous question for more clarity. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34156963/the-bucket-you-are-attempting-to-access-must-be-addressed-using-the-specified-en/34157166#34157166

So I have found a workaround and I didn't use any bucketname, so Jenkins Elastic Beanstalk plugin manages itself, it properly swap the cname and deploy to defined environment, but it creates a new ec2 instance, which is problem in my case as I have redis setup on my ec2 (managed by Elastic Beanstalk) also there are some log file on that ec2, which is not available on new ec2 instance created due to which application does not start due to dependency

Is this possible to deploy to same ec2

Comment: We can't check previous questions.

Comment: i have corrected the link , please check now